# Parse combination of json nested objects and arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
[
    {
        "Profile": {
            "id": "13",
            "user_id": "13",
            "first_name": "samm",
            "profile_image": "13-IMG_169.png",
            "where_from": "abro",
            "where_live": "simba",
            "age": "24",
            "profile_type": null,
            "company_name": "nick",
            "job_title": "developer",
            "industry": "software",
            "education": "bscs",
            "what_you_do": "developement",
            "detail_summery": "summary",
            "location": null,
            "state_id": "1",
            "city_id": "84",
            "favorite_music_bands": "",
            "favorite_teams": "",
            "favorite_books": "",
            "favorite_movies": null,
            "small_intro": "developer"
        }
    }
],
{
    "LookingData": [
        {
            "user_looking_id": "675",
            "looking_id": "1",
            "looking_text": "Expand Professional network"
        },
        {
            "user_looking_id": "456",
            "looking_id": "2",
            "looking_text": "Prospect new business / sales"
        },
        {
            "user_looking_id": "453",
            "looking_id": "3",
            "looking_text": "Share trade expertise / stories"
        },
        {
            "user_looking_id": "123",
            "looking_id": "5",
            "looking_text": "Recruitment"
        },
        {
            "user_looking_id": "654",
            "looking_id": "6",
            "looking_text": "Seeking business partner"
        },
        {
            "user_looking_id": "123",
            "looking_id": "7",
            "looking_text": "Advise"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "MusicData": [
        {
            "user_music_id": "54",
            "music_id": "2",
            "music_name": "Country"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "SportData": [
        {
            "user_sport_id": "234",
            "sport_id": "4",
            "sport_name": "Hockey"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "HobbyData": []
},
[],
{
    "MovieData": [
        {
            "user_movie_id": "645",
            "movie_id": "6",
            "movie_name": "Drama"
        }
    ]
},
[],
{
    "CarrerData": [
        {
            "user_carrer_id": "34",
            "carrer_id": "2",
            "carrer_name": "Marketing"
        },
        {
            "user_carrer_id": "645",
            "carrer_id": "8",
            "carrer_name": "Sales"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

get json Array using this line...

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data //1
                                                                     options:0
                                                                       error:&error];
```

and get profile data using for loop...

```
for (NSDictionary *obj in [responseDict valueForKey:@"Profile"])
{
model.userProfileObj.userFirstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"first_name"]];
}
```

but in this case loop run many of time and assign null value to variables.

after this I want to parse "LookingData" array but I got null value using this code:

```
NSDictionary *dictUserLooking=[responseDict valueForKey:@"LookingData"];
```

Comment: NSLog your respondDict to make sure you're getting what you want in there first.

Comment: The above isn't legal JSON.  You are, at the very least, missing a starting `[`.

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. Are you missing `[]` at the start and end making it an array? Also, you should be iterating over an array, not a dictionary - it looks like your first test should be `[obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]`

Comment: Verify your json first- jsonlint.com

Comment: Note that, given that the JSON, at the outermost level, is an array, you should not be receiving it into an NSDictionary variable.

Comment: Yeah, this JSON file has problems. You're starting the top level array, stopping it after the first element of the array, and then adding more stuff after the array is terminated (which doesn't make sense). Did you make this manually, or did some server actually generate this for you. Not sure which is worse. Lots of ways to fix this or, better, actually just structure the JSON better. But that's not a iOS problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have (assuming the missing outer `[]`) is a JSON array containing elements that are either arrays or "objects" (dictionaries).  The "Profile" data is the contained in the first element of the outer-most array, in this fashion:

outermost array -> single element array -> single element dictionary -> dictionary element for "Profile" -> dictionary containing "Profile" values.

You need to "peel the onion", one layer at a time, to access these values.